# Abrir, editar e salvar um arquivo binário no Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

É possível abrir um arquivo binário e ler seus bits no Python3, editar e salvar um novo binário. Se for possível, como?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Considere um arquivo binário chamado `teste.bin` de exemplo com o seguinte conteúdo (bytes em hexadecimal):

```
 A0 B0 C0 D0 E0 F0
```

O seguinte código lê esses bytes e altera o conteúdo do byte na posição `2` (que inicialmente tem o valor `C0`) para `FF`:

```
with open('teste.bin', 'r+b') as file:
    byte = file.read(1)
    while byte != b'':
        print(byte)
        byte = file.read(1)

    file.seek(2, 0)
    file.write(b'\xFF')
```

Resultado da execução:

```
b'\xa0'
b'\xb0'
b'\xc0'
b'\xd0'
b'\xe0'
b'\xf0'
```

Bytes no arquivo após a execução:

```
A0 B0 FF D0 E0 F0
```

> P.S.: Esse exemplo "edita" o mesmo arquivo. Se você desejar criar um
>   segundo arquivo com as alterações, basta abri-lo com um outro nome de
>   variável. Por exemplo, ao invés e usar o `with open`, você pode fazer
>   assim:
>
> ```
> srcFile = open('teste.bin', 'rb')
> tgtFile = open('teste2.bin', 'wb')
> . . .
> srcFile.read ...
> tgtFile.write ...
> . . .
> srcFile.close()
> tgtFile.close()
> ```
>
> Note que no exemplo inicial eu usei `'r+b'` para abrir o arquivo. O
>   `r` e o `+` indicam que o arquivo vai ser aberto para leitura e para
>   atualização, e o `b` indica que ele deve ser aberto como binário ao
>   invés de texto. Nesse segundo exemplo, eu já abro cada arquivo em um
>   modo distinto: o arquivo de origem (*srcFile*) eu abro apenas como
>   leitura (e por isso uso `'rb'`) e o de destino (*tgtFile*) eu abro
>   apenas como gravação (e por isso uso `'wb'`). O uso do `w` na abertura
>   do arquivo de destino faz com que ele seja sempre truncado (se quiser
>   manter o conteúdo existente você deve abrir com o `r+`).

Answer (score 4):

Para abrir um arquivo em modo binário basta usar o modo `b` na funcão `open`:

```
open("arquivo", "r+b") # Abre arquivo em modo binário para edição
```

A partir daí, todas as funções normais de leitura, escrita e navegação de arquivos estão valendo:

```
with open("arquivo", "r+b") as arquivo:
    byte = arquivo.read(1)
    # altera byte
    arquivo.write(byte)
```

Lembrando que, como o arquivo foi aberto em modo binário, todas as funções vão aceitar e retornar objetos byte.